# Split n long bit logic vector to n individual binary values

Tags: vhdl

I was wondering if there was a method where you can split a n bit long vector for example:

10100111

Into n individual binary units to be used later on? I'm trying to incorporate a method where i can get a 8 bit long vector and have 8 LED's light up depending if that n'th value is 0 or 1. Googling the question returns people cutting up a larger vector into smaller ones, but if we were to have 16 bits for example then i'd have to make 16 separate variables for it work using:

```
entity test is
port (
 myVector : in std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);
 LED : out std_logic_vector(16 downto 0)
);
END test

architecture behavior of test is
 SIGNAL led1 : std_logic;
 ...
 SIGNAL led16 : std_logic;
BEGIN

 led1 <= myVector(0);
 ...
 led16 <= myVector(16);

 LED(1) <= '1' when led1 = '1' else '0';
 ...
 LED(16) <= '1' when led16 = '1' else '0';
END behavior
```

Doesn't seem tidy when it needs to be repeated several times in the code.

Comment: From the code it looks like you could just do `LED <= myVector;`, so what are the additional requirements?  Why can't you just make reference to `myVector(n)` when needed?

Comment: There wasn't really a problem with what i wrote (albeit a few syntax fixes). 

The problem is that in order to split up a 16 bit vector into 16 separate variables, and then individually call them one by one for every LED at N. So that way i'll end up with 32 lines of code, i was wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing it. Apologies i didn't emphasize the question well enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to declare and assign to identifiers with different names, then you have to make a line for each name, since there is no loop statement for identifier name manipulation in VHDL.

But VHDL provides arrays, where you can loop over the entries, like with this example code:

```
...
   signal led_sig  : std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);
begin
  loop_g: for idx in myVector'range generate
    led_sig(idx) <= myVector(idx);
    LED(idx)     <= '1' when led_sig(idx) = '1' else '0';
  end generate;
...
```

Where the assigns are equivalent to the shorter:

```
led_sig <= myVector;
LED     <= led_sig;
```